# JQuery Accordion 2 Columns vs 1 Column

Tags: jquery, css

I have an Accordian that Im trying to modify because the Accordian is too large (too much height)

I need to change this from 1 Column into 2 Columns.  That appear side-by-side.

The reason is with the single Column approach, there is way too much height because of the many items.

Here is the JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/Jv8Ta/

Im trying to make this so the Column that isnt selected, to remain intact- that is without moving.

Does anyone have an idea about how to approach this?

Comment: Your example only has one column. And what do you mean by "remain intact"? Like collapse if something in the other column is selected?

Comment: @fudgey Yes my example only has 1 Column and I need 2 Columns. Thats true that if an element in the 1st Column should colapse if an element in the 2nd Column is selected. Otherwise if you select something in 1 Column, the other Column shouldnt move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jv8Ta/10/))

Basically I changed the script to point to all of the `dt`s instead of just the `dl`s inside the first column.

Comment: I expanded upon your work to provide those 2 columns side-by-side

Comment: They should be side-by-side, it's just that the jsFiddle window is narrow and floating them left makes them drop down. Just expand the jsFiddle window.

Comment: is there any benefit to have 2 contentbox classes as I demonstrated?  This functions great btw.

Comment: Only if you want the two content boxes to act independently from each other.